# Spring JPA, SpEL parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in expression, 'comma(,)'

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have to retrieve some specific data from oracle 12c using spring JPA which are separated by comma (,).

Ex - Branch

```
  ID                    Location
---------              ----------
  101                    NL,MX,USA
  102                    UK,IND,BLG
  103                    UK,NL,AUS



@Query(value = "select * from branch m where lower(m.location) like %:loc% offset :offset rows fetch next :limit rows only",nativeQuery = true)
        List<Location> getBranchListByLocation(@Param("loc") String loc,@Param("offset") int offset,@Param("limit") limit)
```

But when i pass loc value as "NL" then the following error has occurred.

```
   spelparseexception: el1041e: after parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'comma(,)'
```

Is there an alternative way to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The `%` characters need to be contained in string literals and concatenated with the `:loc` bind variable:

```sql
select *
from   branch m
where  lower(m.location) like '%' || :loc || '%'
offset :offset rows
fetch next :limit rows only
```

Alternatively, you can prepend and append `%` to the `loc` variable in Java and then just use `:loc` without the wrapping `%`s in the SQL query.

*(Note: you are using `lower` so you want to pass in `nl` and not `NL`.)*

---

However, you will find if you pass the `:loc` value `in` then it will match `in` as well as `ind` and `ink`. If you want to match the full delimited item then you want to include the surrounding commas in the match:

```sql
select *
from   branch m
where  ',' || lower(m.location) || ',' like '%,' || :loc || ',%'
offset :offset rows
fetch next :limit rows only
```

Comment: @MTO, I tried both, but it does not work, the same error will occur